# MongoDb inserts and updates not showing up in the Frontend

Tags: php, mongodb

I am working on a php application which makes a rest API call  and fetches data from the Mongodb server . The Query being used in the API is a geospatial query.

I inserted a record in the backend using the Robo Mongo tool . When I run the query in the Robo mongo tool I get the correct resultset with the newly inserted record but the response of the API call still shows the old resultset i.e. without the newly inserted recode.

What could be causing this?

Comment: "What could be causing this?" - Many things. Queries are different. The api talks to another db. A stale cache somewhere between (and including) api server and db. And so on.

Comment: The query is the same - db.getCollection('location').find({'geolocation.loc': {$geoWithin: {$box: [[ -71.3227472602295,42.07979786257836 ],[ -71.20550253977052,42.10527457911824 ]]}}})

Comment: I tried clearing the cache of the browser...but it did not help

Comment: What cache did you clear? Browser cache?

Comment: Yes..I cleared the browser cache

Comment: Yeah, I meant another cache. Memcached or what-have-you. Check db configurations too.